# Infer argument type based on a prior argument's generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type defined as follows:

```
export type LogBuilder<
  T extends Logger<U>,
  U extends LoggerOptions
> = (options: U) => T;
```

I can use this as follows:

```
interface WinstonLogger extends Logger<WinstonOptions> {
  // Object.keys(Winston.config.syslog.levels)
  emerg: Log;
  alert: Log;
  crit: Log;
  error: Log;
  warning: Log;
  notice: Log;
  info: Log;
  debug: Log;
}

const declareWinstonLogger: LogBuilder<WinstonLogger, WinstonOptions> = (options) => {
  return ...;
}
```

Notice that the `WinstonLogger` extends with a generic type `WinstonOptions`.

Is there a way in `LogBuilder` to infer `U` from the generic type `T<U>`, so that I don't need to specify the second type in `LogBuilder<WinstonLogger, WinstonOptions>`?

---

I know I can define `LogBuilder` to have a default value of `LoggerOptions` for `U`:

```
export type LogBuilder<
  T extends Logger<U>,
  U extends LoggerOptions = LoggerOptions
> = (options: U) => T;
```

and I know Typescript has an `infer` keyword, which I attempted unsuccessfully to solve this problem. I'm hoping there's some way to combine these to drop the need to declare the second type generic in `LogBuilder`, and have that default to `WinstonOptions`, and having the above `LogBuilder` definition has it default to `LoggerOptions` - is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `infer` keyword should work here.

```
export type LogBuilder<
  T extends Logger<any>,
> = (options: T extends Logger<infer U> ? U : never) => T;
```

We can extract the type `U` from `Logger` in a conditional type for the `options` parameter.